# Unable to choose image to display in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to display an image from my mobile phone into an imageview, to upload to firebase storage. However, I am unable to select a file from my phone to upload.

I am currently following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNcd41C-IEE and on the 11:00-minute mark so there is still more code I need to add.

Screenshots of the activity: 
[Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHD8u.png)
[Screenshot displaying issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB43G.png)

Code:

```
public class ChallengeUploadAdd extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE=1;

private Button chooseImage, btnUploadImage;
private TextView viewGallery;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private TextView view_Gallery;
private EditText imgDescription;
private Uri imgUrl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_challenge_upload_add);
    chooseImage=findViewById(R.id.chooseImage);
    btnUploadImage=findViewById(R.id.btnUploadImage);


    view_Gallery=findViewById(R.id.viewGallery);

    imgDescription=findViewById(R.id.imgDescription);
    imgPreview=findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFileChoose();
        }
    });
}

private void showFileChoose(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("images/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data
            != null && data.getData() !=null){
        imgUrl=data.getData();

        Picasso.get().load(imgUrl).into(imgPreview);
    }
}
```

}

Any help as to why I am unable to choose an image from my phone will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hy try this code as image chooser, it will take you directly to your gallery.

Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);

SELECT_PHOTO is 1

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer Thank you very much, this worked.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: You could upvote my answer in the answer section so people can learn from it

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer Sure thing, I have accepted the answer and upvoted. Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);`

where `SELECT_PHOTO is 1`

Answer (score 0):

To start with add permission in the manifest and also ask runtime permission from users.

[Read More about Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

[Use this Dexter Library to ask runtime permission super easy!](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

I usually go with this code giving me both options for taking image from camera or choose from gallery.

```
protected void pickImageFromGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    context.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 1);


}

protected void pickImageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

and handle Results of both in onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:

                try{

                    if (data != null) {
                        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);


                        userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(photo);

                    } else {

                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    try {

                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

                        userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
```